# Statistics on a link clicked from my website/Facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, google-analytics, share

I have a simple FB app (Landing page) and i have a "Share this with your friends" option on it.

Here is the code:

```
  $title=urlencode('INMORIA');
  $url=urlencode('http://www.facebook.com/INMORIA');
  $summary=urlencode('Hey! I have just found this incredible band!       Check them out!.');
  $image=urlencode('images/logga.png');
  ?>
  <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
                    SHARE THIS WITH YOUR FRIENDS
   </a>
```

Is it some way that i can see who have clicked and shared my content?

Maybe Google analytics or does Facebook have something i can use?

The reason i ask is that i want to have a contest on my page and i want to give those who share my page a price. Like a free CD, T-shirt or something.

Or is it some other way to do this? I know that i can upload a photo on my page and see who shared the photo but i want that pop-up with the description and stuff to be the object that is shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can track events with google analytics: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: Alright! That could be what i´m looking for! I will check it out! Thanx so much!

Comment: Ok i have made a Google analytic tracking code config and put it in the code of the page where the sharer is. Now i dont get it to work with the : <a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
                 SHARE THIS WITH YOUR FRIENDS
                </a>

Comment: Where in the <a onClick""> should i put the <a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>  (This is the ex code from the tracking guide. When i put it in the original code it just stops to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I would do it like this: onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);window.open();"